# How do I use pseudo-elements to display content after the main item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following look:

[image]

I want to place the heart on the top right of the price box.   And I've managed to create it but the placement of the heart is hardwired.  And if I change $89k to something bigger, the price box increases in width and the heart is misplaced.

Is there a way that `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element can know (or inherit) the width of the price box and place itself accordingly?

Or am I going about this in a wrong manner?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  transform: scale(3.0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.home-price {
  color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  /* width: 50px; */
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

/* Favorite Marker */
.home-price:before {
  content: "♥";
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 39px;      
  top: -8px;
  text-shadow:  white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px;
}

.home-hot {
  background-color: #C81845;
  border-color: #F5F2F3;
}
```

```html
  <div style="height: 25px;margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="home-price home-hot">      
      $89K
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Makyen Done. Basically forgot. I do, however prefer to use CodePen since it keeps all my snippets in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can just use `right: 0;` instead of using hardcoded pixels for `left`, since you always want the icon to be displayed in the right corner anyway. There is no need to know the exact width of the element.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  transform: scale(3.0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.home-price {
  color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  /* width: 50px; */
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

/* Favorite Marker */
.home-price:before {
  content: "♥";
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;      
  top: -8px;
  text-shadow:  white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px,   
    white 0px 0px 1px;
}

.home-hot {
  background-color: #C81845;
  border-color: #F5F2F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-price home-hot">      
  $80009K
</div>
<div class="home-price home-hot">      
  $89K
</div>
<div class="home-price home-hot">      
  $80009,99K
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick!  I wish I could upvote a million times.

Comment: @AngryHacker Happy to help, just a single mark as answer would be nice :)

Comment: Was gonna do it right away, but SO makes you wait 12 minutes.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, thx!